# SWIFT - Convert String to UIKit element

Tags: ios, swift, string, uikit

maybe it's an awkward question but it is possible to convert a String to an UIKit element. By that I mean :

I have the following UIViewController

```
import UIKit

class BlurVC: UIViewController {


    let bg: UIImageView = {
       let image = UIImageView()
        image.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_9293")
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.backgroundColor = .red
        return image
    }()

    let blurView: UIVisualEffectView = {
        let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        bg.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(bg)
        blurView.frame = bg.bounds
        bg.addSubview(blurView)

        setBlurButton()
    }

    func setBlurButton() {

        let blurEffects = ["extraLight", "light", "dark"]

        for index in 0..<blurEffects.count{

            let button = UIButton()
            button.setTitle(blurEffects[index], for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setBlurEffect(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10  + index * 30, width: 100, height: 30)
            view.addSubview(button)
        }
    }

    func setBlurEffect(_ sender: UIButton){
        print(sender.titleLabel?.text)
        if let blurEffect = sender.titleLabel?.text {
            blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: ".\(blurEffect)")
        }
    }
}
```

I create 3 buttons dynamically with the title of 3 UIBlurEffectStyle parameters.

I want next set the value of UIBlurEffectStyle based on the title label.

Of course xCode warn me that it cannot convert a String to an UIBlurEffectStyle.

Can I cast this String to an UIBlurEffectStyle ? If yes, how to do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIBlurEffectStyle` is based on an `Int`, so there's no automatic conversion from a `String`.

But you can do it manually. Here's an extension with an init that takes the `UIBlurEffectStyle` cases as `String`s:

```
extension UIBlurEffectStyle {

    init?(with string: String) {
        switch string {
        case "extraLight":
            self = .extraLight
        case "light":
            self = .light
        case "dark":
            self = .dark
        case "regular":
            self = .regular
        case "prominent":
            self = .prominent
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Not this is a fallible initializer. Since it's stringly typed, you want to verify it worked before using it.

Comment: Plus 1 but it doesn't work for iOS 9.x. You need to add some `@available` checks.

Comment: You're right @OzgurVatansever, the last two cases should either be commented out or handled properly for pre-iOS 10. I didn't want to load up a whole project so I was just using a playground :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extension:

```
extension UIBlurEffectStyle {
    static func styleFromString(_ string: String) -> UIBlurEffectStyle {
        switch string {
        case "extraLight":
            return .extraLight
        case "light":
            return .light
        case "dark":
            return .dark
        default:
            return .regular /* NOTE: .regular is not available in < iOS 10 */
        }
    }
}
```

To use in your case:

```
blurView.effect  = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.styleFromString("blurEffect"))
```

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ good point. Thanks. Will update the answer for the benefit of anyone will read it.

Comment: Thx too for this issue, It works fine too @janusbalatbat